# Employ bracket matching for R in windows

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to get R to match brackets/quotes in Windows the way a Mac GUI does? On macs, when you enter a bracket or quote it automatically brings up the closing bracket/quote.

For instance, in Macs, when you type

```
summary(
```

You get

```
summary()
```

But in Windows RGUI you simply get

```
summary(
```

I am getting sick of having to type parens/brackets/quotes after each function I input and then counting to make sure I have enough.

Thanks for the help.
Paul

Answer (score 4):

Try [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/). It'll change your life.

Comment: Or Eclipse/Architect or Emacs or Live-R or Revolution-R or JGR or Notepad++ or Tinn-R or basically any text editor that isn't Notepad.  They all do bracket matching.